# NppExec - Command unkown to NppExec, Environment variable is set

Tags: path, notepad++, raku, nppexec

I am trying to execute a small perl6 script via Notepad++ and NppExec.
My system is Windows 10 and i set the PATH variable properly to C:\rakudo\bin where the perl6 executable is. When i am executing the script via normal console with:

```
perl6 "path/to/script.pl6"
```

it gets executed without a problem.

However, when i execute the exact same command in NppExec as following:

```
CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
perl6 "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

i get the error: CreateProcess() failed with error code 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Obviously, the command "perl6" is unkown to NppExec... 
My question: How can i make the PATH variable known to NppExec or is this problem related to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the PATH that NppExec knows with the following NppExec command:

```
env_set PATH
```

So you can check if the path to perl is there or not. A rather simple way to run perl would be using the full path to perl6 in you original script. Btw, you can use `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the full path now. But also and important it is possible to use the env variable. One just has to add the file ending. So: CD "$(CURRENT_PATH)"
"perl6.bat" "$(FILE_NAME)" is working

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by entering the full path to the perl executable. So my NppExec command now looks like:

```
CD "$(CURRENT_PATH)"
"C:\rakudo\bin\perl6.bat" "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

and the script gets executed properly.

It is also possible to use the env variable. One has to add the file ending:

```
CD "$(CURRENT_PATH)"
perl6.bat "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like NppExec is smart enough to search for applications in environment PATH. However it does not add `.bat` extension automatically. In my case **adding `.bat` solved the problem**. So this works:

```
gradle.bat
```